# Combining activerecord-reputation-system queries with paging

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

I am using the activerecord-reputation-system gem located here https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system. In my application I have posts which I want to sort by votes using the

`ActiveRecord::Base.find_with_reputation(:reputation_name, :scope, :find_options)`

method from the gem. I also have enough posts that I need them to be paged and searchable. However whenever I call the page or search methods that normally work on my post collection I get a method does not exist error. My usual collection call looks like this

```
Post.all.text_search(params[:query]).order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

I am using Kaminari for paging. Does anyone know how to combine the find_with_reputation method with other query parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a normal Active Record finder method:

```
Post.page(params[:page]).per(20).find_with_reputation(:reputation_name, :scope, :find_options)
```

For example, if your post has reputation `votes`:

```
Post.page(params[:page]).per(20).find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:order => 'votes DESC, created_at DESC'})
```

This will find posts ordered by reputation, creation date and paginate them.

You can also create a scope in your model for that finder:

```
def self.most_voted
  find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:order => 'votes DESC'})
end
```

then use:

```
Post.page(params[:page]).per(20).most_voted
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. Unfortunately there seems to be a bug with using activerecord-reputation-system with kaminari. When using the paging helper method in the view an error is thrown for undefined method current_page

Comment: This worked perfectly. Be careful if you already have a votes attribute on the model as it will reference this instead of activerecord-reputation's vote count.

Comment: @BinaryX - Did you ever get past this, specifically the current_page issue? I am experiencing the same issue. Although, I did enjoy adding a scope to my query - it's much more readable now.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:
[Using Active Record Reputation System gem, no sorting happens when I sort by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617224/using-active-record-reputation-system-gem-no-sorting-happens-when-i-sort-by-vot)

```
@posts = Post.page(params[:page]).reorder('votes desc').find_with_reputation(:votes, :all)
```