# Using Active Record Reputation System gem, no sorting happens when I sort by votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, railscasts

Following the RailsCast for the reputation system gem, I added the following code to my microposts_controller

```
def index
  @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page]).find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc")
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
end
```

But no sorting happens in my index action aside from the default scope I set in my model

In my micropost model I have

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :retweets
    has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
```

If I change the default scope to

```
default_scope -> { order('votes DESC') }
```

It works how I want it to for the index page only but breaks all of my other pages.

I tried removing the default scope and leaving in the find_with_reputation method but it still doesn't order by votes.

I also tried defining the scope in a method in the micropost model like this

```
  def self.popular
    find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:order => 'votes desc'})
  end
```

And make the code in the microposts_controller like this

```
  def index
    @microposts = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page]).popular
    @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
  end
```

It still does not sort by votes.

Here is a copy of the log output from visiting the micropost index page
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9745552

Here is a link to the gem https://github.com/NARKOZ/activerecord-reputation-system/tree/rails4

My routes.rb for microposts looks like this

```
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy, :index] do
    member { post :vote }
    member { post :retweet}
  end
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

### **Update**

My home page feed is designed differently from what I'm doing for the Micropost Index feed. Maybe comparing what works to what doesn't will help pinpoint the issue.

I have a Static Pages Controller which sets its scope for the home action like this

```
def home
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

In the user model I define the feed method used in the static pages controller like so

```
def feed
  Micropost.from_users_followed_by_including_replies(self)
end
```

the `from_users_followed_by_including_replies(self)` method is a scope i set in the micropost model

```
scope :from_users_followed_by_including_replies, lambda { |user| followed_by_including_replies(user) }

 def self.followed_by_including_replies(user)
      followed_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                       WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
      where("user_id IN (#{followed_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id OR to_id = :user_id",
            { :user_id => user })
 end
```

Maybe I need to adapt a similar approach to the Index action for the Microposts controller

Comment: does it work without default scope?

Comment: Unfortunately no. When i remove the default scope it still doesn't sort correctly. Here is a copy of my log without the default scope https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9766989

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

In getting my hands on the code, I've found the real problem stems from the use of `default_scope`.

The original `order()` clause specified in your default scope is still being applied, even when adding your own `order()`.

As a side note, this issue was *kind of* fixed in Rails 4.0, but the behavior was reverted in 4.0.1.

The solution was to apply a `reorder()`

```
# model
def self.popular
  reorder('votes desc').find_with_reputation(:votes, :all)
end

# controller
def index
  @microposts = Micropost.page(params[:page]).popular
end
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It seems that using the `paginate` method *directly* may not work with `activerecord-reputation-system`,

However, I found some examples showing that you can use the `will_paginate` `page` and `per` methods:

Perhaps it will work like this:

```
Micropost.page(params[:page]).per(30).find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc")
```

Or with the model scope like this:

```
def self.popular
  find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: 'votes desc')
end
```

you could do this:

```
Micropost.page(params[:page]).per(30).popular
```

Also, as a side note, your routes file is a little strange with multiple `member` blocks, when only one is necessary. I would make it look like this:

```
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy, :index] do
  member do
    post :vote
    post :retweet
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fix in my routes file. I tried adjusting the scope to how you have it, as well as editing the pagination call and still no luck. I also removed the pagination completely and it is still only sorting by the default scope.

Comment: This was exactly the issue!